# Levitate + Glide = Sustained Flight?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

The transmutation spell [Glide](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Glide) includes this clause (highlighted in bold):

> You take no damage from falls (as if from feather fall). In addition,
>   you can move up to 5 feet in any horizontal direction for every 1 foot
>   you fall, at a speed of 60 feet per round. You cannot use this spell
>   to actually gain height, merely coast in other directions as you fall.
>   **If subjected to a strong wind or *any other effect that causes you to rise* you can take advantage of it in order to increase the
>   distance you can glide.** The spell ends as soon as your feet touch
>   the ground regardless of its remaining duration. If the spell expires
>   while you are still in the air you fall the remaining distance as
>   normal.

Does that mean that if the transmutation spell [Levitate](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Levitate) is active on you *at the same time* then you may continually move horizontally even if you have no distance left to fall?

How exactly would this work? Do these two spells interact in any particular way?

Would it make any difference if another character was under the effect of Levitate or Levitate was cast on a heavy object and you were connected to either by a rope so that either "causes you to rise" when that object or character rises?

It seems that the spell Levitate is the only means that would "cause you to rise". Glide is otherwise still a very capable spell, it's not quite flying, but sure is "falling with style".

Comment: @GarretGang Please don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 4):

While [levitating](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/levitate.html) you're not falling, and Glide only functions while you're falling, so Levitate interferes with Glide while the former is active.

Levitate can certainly be used to achieve a greater height to later fall from though, and therefore can help Glide in that way.

Comment: What do you suppose the text of Glide could be referring to with "causes you to rise" to increase gliding distance?

Comment: @TREB Wind, being picked up by a dragon and dropped, dimension door… all kinds of things that raise you and then let you fall. Levitate counts, but only after it expires, because you don't fall until then.

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of glide, it works while falling.  It's not clear whether levitate would interfere with the act of falling.

In the case of being tied to a levitating object, I would think the rope would need to be cut or dropped in order for glide to trigger.

An entirely RAW solution is that a character could be lifted to the max height of levitate, then cast glide as the spell runs out.  Max height of levitate would be 200 feet per level (20 ft per 6 second turn, 10 turns in a minute).  Glide multiplies that by 5 ft, and lasts till you hit the ground.  So 1000 ft per caster level.

Comment: Doesn't levitate have verbage about floating gently down to the ground?